# Apply GLM Estimates to Table in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, glm

In SAS the `proc logistic` function allows you to run a logistical regression, and then as final options to the statement you can select `output out = <newtablename>` and `Pred = <phat>`. This will take the table you ran the regression on and add a column (called 'Estimated Probability' by default) to it that has the corresponding applied estimates.

Is there a way to perform this same functionality in R? I can run the GLM and obtain the coefficients, however is there a function that will automatically apply these in order to obtain an estimated probability for each row?

This is what I am trying to replicate in R (really just the final lines):

```
proc logistic data = model_data_final DESC;
class 
    age (PARAM=Ref REF='2');
model claim = 
    age 

    price1 
    percent1 
    percent2 
    percent3 
    percent4 
    percent5 
    percent6 
    percent7 
    /  

    outroc=ROCDATA ROCEPS = 0.005;

output out = RegProbability Pred = phat;
quit;
```

R regression...

```
RegProbability <- glm(claim ~ age + price1 + percent1 + percent2 
+ percent3 + percent4 + percent5 + percent6 + percent7, 
family = binomial, data = model_data_final)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try PREDICT() after to get the predictions.

Comment: `predict(RegProbability, type="response")` will return predictions on the probability scale for each row of data. To add this as a column to your data frame do `model_data_final$predictions = predict(RegProbability, type="response")`. To get predictions on the log odds scale, `predict(RegProbability)`, since that's the default. To predict with new data, just provide a different data frame (that contains all the columns in your model) with the `newdata` argument: `predict(RegProbability, newdata=new_data, type="response")`.

Comment: @Reeza: Proper capitalization is needed. There is no `PREDICT` function in base R. I suppose there might be one with that spelling in some package, but if so you should specify it. To `jrl`, What you should do is type `?predict` at your console and do read some more basic introductory material on how to use R regression-associated functions.

Comment: See my comment above. Also, you can just type `predict` rather than `predict.glm`. `predict` dispatches `predict.glm` automatically when you give it a `glm` model object.